# Find level in navigation structure?

Tags: xslt, navigation, sitecore

I have a sitecore 6 solution where the body background image changes depending on wich level you are currently on;

Home
- Subpage 1
-- Sub-subpage 1
-- Sub-subpage 2
--- Sub sub subpage 1
- Subpage 2
-- Sub-subpage 1

So i have a bg image for "Home", a bg image for "Subpage 1" and "Subpage 2" and a bg image for "Sub-subpage 1, 2" etc.

How would i check for the level in xslt?

Comment: When downvoting a question please also specify the reason. It helps other users understand and might give the poster of the question an idea on how to be more specific ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's kinda hard to say, as I'm not quite sure I've understood the question fully.

But one way would be to use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(ancestor::*)"/>
```

or

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(ancestor::node())"/>
```

See this page for an explanation of the difference:

http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N2193.html

Comment: This is also his 3rd question that is rather vague.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that too, maybe he needs a few pointers in asking questions on SO. :)

Comment: Thx - that did the trick. Sorry if my questions are vague - i'll try to be more specific next time around.